# wp-pagenavi not working on custom query wordpress

Tags: wordpress, pagination, woocommerce

I face very weird issue on `wp-pagenavi` plugin. I am using WooCommerce plugin it works perfectly. Now i make a page template and want to show all that products which product type is bundle, my products show but wp-pagenavi not working. I also try on blog page its working perfect there but not in my page template.

Here is my code:

Page Template Name

```
<?php
    /*
    Template Name: Bundle Products
    */
    get_header();
?>
```

My custome Query

```
<?php
    $paged = get_query_var('page') ? get_query_var('page') : 1;

    $gb_bundle_args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'product',
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                    'paged' => $paged,
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'product_type',
                            'field' => 'name',
                            'terms' => 'bundle'
                        )
                    )
            );
    $gb_bundle_qry = new WP_Query($gb_bundle_args);

    if($gb_bundle_qry->have_posts()) :
        while($gb_bundle_qry->have_posts()) :
            $gb_bundle_qry->the_post();

            the_title();
            echo '<br />';
        endwhile;
    else :
        echo "No Bundle Products";
    endif;

    wp_pagenavi();

    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

I searched alot about this but nothing found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass

```
      wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $gb_bundle_qry ) ); 
      wp_reset_query();
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: it shows me pages and when i click on a page number ex. 2 the page goes to second page but my posts are not change

Comment: ok its work ... i made some changes like "$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;"